# Converting code to lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to convert my "long" code to simpler, lambda driven code. Idea is to get values from enum. If first value higher or lower, return it and break the lambda from going futher. I do not know where to go from here. Lambda returns code from enum fine and it calculates differences fine. My problem is getting the value to return and/or break lambda from executing further once difference is found.

Code that does not work:

```
BiFunction<Map<String, Integer>,Map<String, Integer>,Integer> biFunction = (m1, m2) -> {
    enumWords.forEach(word -> {
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if(m1.get(word) > m2.get(word)){
            returnValue = m1.get(word).compareTo(m2.get(word));
            break;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;     
};
```

This is the code(pre-lambda) that worked:

```
BiFunction<Map<String, Integer>,Map<String, Integer>,Integer> biFunction = (m1, m2) -> {
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if(m1.get("Love") > m2.get("Love")){
                returnValue = -1;
            }else if(m1.get("Love") < m2.get("Love")){
                returnValue = 1;
            }else{
                if(m1.get("You") > m2.get("You")){
                    returnValue = -1;
                }else if(m1.get("You") < m2.get("You")){
                    returnValue = 1;
                }else{
                    if(m1.get("Me") > m2.get("Me")){
                        returnValue = -1;
                    }else if(m1.get("Me") < m2.get("Me")){
                        returnValue = 1;
                    }else{
                        if(m1.get("Forever") > m2.get("Forever")){
                            returnValue = -1;
                        }else if(m1.get("Forever") < m2.get("Forever")){
                            returnValue = 1;
                        }else{
                            if(m1.get("Give") > m2.get("Give")){
                                returnValue = -1;
                            }else if(m1.get("Give") < m2.get("Give")){
                                returnValue = 1;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Same lyrics!");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: instead of `forEach`, I would go the approach of using `filter` on the stream and then after that you can do `findFirst` which returns an `Optional<?>` where ? is the Stream type. Something like `Optional<Integer> opt = enumWords.stream().filter( word -> m1.get(word) > m2.get(word) ).map( m1.get(word).compareTo(m2.get(word) ) ).findFirst();`

Comment: Your attempts are contradicting. Can you post your working non-lambda code to show what you actually want to do? Unfortunately, your explanation isn’t helpful either. The only thing that is not explaining your *attempted solution* is “Idea is to get values from enum”, but there are no `enum`s involved. So what is your actual goal?

Comment: in Enum there are Keywords, I'm going trough song lyrics and if 1st keyword appears in one song more than the other, it goes "up" on list. If they have same number of first keyword, it goes to 2nd and so on. Thing is that it was hardcoded before, I wanted to make it so it can be used even if someone changes enum words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tried but I think this should work:

```
return enumWords.stream()
     // filter when they are different
     .filter(word -> m1.get(word) != m2.get(word))
     // stop search at first occurrence
     .findFirst()
     // compare and get the value 1 or -1
     .map(word -> m1.get(word).compareTo(m2.get(word)))
     // return the value or 0 in case is not found
     .orElse(0);
```

**UPDATE**

@Holger suggested another solution I think it worth to mention:

```
return enumWords.stream()
           .mapToInt(word -> m1.get(word).compareTo(m2.get(word)))
           .filter(i -> i != 0)
           .findFirst()
           .orElse(0);
```

Comment: You can simplify it by moving the `compareTo` to the front: `enumWords.stream() .mapToInt(word -> m1.get(word).compareTo(m2.get(word))) .filter(i -> i != 0) .findFirst() .orElse(0)`

Comment: Thanks @Holger, I think it also more efficient, there is only one `get` for each `enumWords` element.